# Read url link from message graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know how can I get the "real" url from message with facebook's graph api. For exapmle when I give:

me?fields=home.fields(message)

I get:
...UK teenager Hannah Smith: http://bbc.in/1eWCFnv\n\nThe social networking site pledges...

The url is just a text. But in original post it is a link that points to some resource. So, my question is: how can I get the urls as link?

Comment: Converting links into clickable items is most likely done outside of the API (possibly even on the client side). You might have to simply scan the text and extract any links.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the additional fields that you want to retrieve. Try this

```
me/home?fields=message,link
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what Im looking for. I want to get links from message text itself.